# Asp.net Membership provider with custom textboxes to login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I installed ASPNET Membership provider.Now i create a Login form(This is not a default asp.net login form).But i saw lots of example in internet they use default login page.. So. i wanted to know how to do login with this?

My aspx code here

```
<form  name="form-area"  class="form-area" runat="server">
                    <h1>User Login</h1>
                    <p>Please Enter Username & Password to login</p>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtusr" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtpw" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                    <div class="form-area-bottom">&nbsp;</div>
                </form>
```

Here i create a User Roles in ASPNET administration website.I wanted to know about when button click how to Login

I saw some example like this..Can i use this

```
protected void loginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool isLogin = Membership.ValidateUser(loginUser.UserName, loginUser.Password);
    if (isLogin)
    {
        loginUser.Visible = true;
        Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(loginUser.UserName, true);
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the core off all is

```
 bool isLogin = Membership.ValidateUser(loginUser.UserName, loginUser.Password);
```

but you take care to handles the correct event.
you're using custom login form so you need to intercept click button  validate user within that event.then you can perform the action that you need.

i hope that can help you.